# Regplace , regex with php doesnt work

Tags: php, regex

```
    <?php
        $target="This is a test | dont present me!";
        $pattern="/\| (.*?)/";
       $target=  preg_replace($pattern, '', $target);
        echo $target;
    ?>
```

I am trying to get rid of everything that is from the pipe line towards the right.. but the regular expression doest work. what am I missing?

Comment: Probably too many question marks and parentheses - try "/\| .*/"

Comment: yeah it worked.... where did my code fail , however?

Comment: `.*?` is ungreedy, i.e. it will match the _shortest_ match (which here is 0 characters for that subpattern) instead of the _longest_ match (which the greedy `.*` does, and would be until end of string).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$pattern="/\| .*/";
```

You simply don't need the parentheses, since you don't repeat it and don't reuse in the replacement.  And the question mark is superfluous after the `*`, both are quantifiers.  (And @wrikken's comment is right, `*?` is the lazy version of `*`.)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $target="This is a test | dont present me!";
    $pattern="/\|.*/";
    $target=  preg_replace($pattern, '', $target);
    echo $target;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why the `?` in your pattern?

Try with `/\|(.*)/` or even just `/\|.*/` if you don't really need grouping.

Comment: True. But since you want to eat everything that follows the `|`, don't be afraid being greedy :o)